# Javafx: jpeg file exists but the Image constructor throws IllegalArgumentException !Why?

Tags: java, image, javafx

Why is following code throwing this exception?

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
```

Here is the code:

```
File ff=new File("images/a.jpg");
if (ff.exists()) {Image ii=new Image(ff.getPath());}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html):

> All URLs supported by URL can be passed to the constructor. If the
>   passed string is not a valid URL, but a path instead, the Image is
>   searched on the classpath in that case.

The path you get is a relative path, but not (necessarily) relative to the classpath, which is how the `Image` constructor is interpreting it.

Try

```
Image ii=new Image(ff.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm());
```

or, depending on how you have your project structure set up

```
Image ii=new Image(getClass().getResource("images/a.jpg").toExternalForm());
```

The second version will work if the image file is packaged along with the application in a jar file.

Comment: Works! But what if I use the absolute path?

Comment: I just remembered it should be File ff=new File("file:images\\a.jpg");Can you tell me Why?

Comment: I think it will still work; but getting a URL and then converting to a string is safer, as the docs state the the string passed in is interpreted as a URL.

Comment: Sure, the `toString` method of the `URI` and `URL` objects probably return the result of calling `toExternalForm`. But it's always better to use the method documented to do what you actually want. And of course that's a different value to the value you had: `ff.getPath()`.